# In a simple circuit with only cell and wire, where is the electrical energy lost (what causes potential difference)?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries, dissipation

Imagine a simple cell circuit with a nine volts cell. Because of the cell, there is a potential difference of 9V between 2 points on the circuit. Because $$Energy at a point = charge * electric potential$$ The potential difference inn this case is 9v which means there is a energy difference of 9* charge.

there is a difference in energy between these two points which is equal to charge x  potential difference between those two points  . This means there is loss in energy between the points. Where has this extra energy been lost?

Remember I have not conected any resistor  or bulb .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for gradual energy losses that occur inside all batteries (giving them a limited shelf life) there is no energy lost by your 9 volt battery unless it does work to deliver current (charge) to a circuit connected to its terminals.

The potential difference, or voltage $V$ between two points is the work (energy) required per unit  charge to move the charge between the two points. So a 9 volt battery does 9 Joules of work to move 1 coulomb of charge from its positive to negative terminal around a circuit, even if the circuit consists of only a wire.

The potential difference between the battery terminals is due to the internal work done by the battery in converting chemical potential energy to electrical potential energy at its terminals. The gravity analogy is the work you do lifting an object giving it gravitational potential energy.

Hope this helps